# User privileges

Tags: permissions, privileges

I have certain files and folders whose read, write, execute privileges I want to keep locked for certain users. I can use `chmod XXX <filepath>` for locking file privileges, but the user can certainly delete that file, although he cannot access it. Is there a way to prevent him from doing so? Plus will that work on folders too?

Comment: try `chmod 700 /filepath`

Comment: Yes, but the "other" could simply right click, go into file permissions and make it readable/writable/executable again

Comment: Better option will be to alias `rm` command with `sudo rm` so that every time you delete something it will ask for the password and you can protect your files.Because `chmod` doesn't work!

Comment: No, others dont know my sudo password.

Comment: Okay, I think I'll try to alias the `rm` with a sudo `rm`, but will it also work against a right click+delete??

Comment: No that won't work with right-click delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be able to be done by changing the ownership of them to `root`:

```
chown root:root /path/to/file
```

You can then control individual permissions with `chmod`:

```
chmod a+r,og-w /path/to/file
```

The letter before `+`/`-` is the user(s) which will be affected:

> the user who owns it (`u`),
> other users in the file's group (`g`),
> other users not in the file's group (`o`),
> or all users (`a`).
>
> If none of these are given, the effect is as if `a` were  given,

The letter after `+`/`-` is the permission which will be given/removed:

```
r   Read
w   Write
x   Execute (for files); or list folder contents (for dirs)
```

---

#### Note about deletions

The permissions of a user to delete a file are determined by the **folder the file is in**, not the write permissions of the file itself.

You'll need to `chown` to root and `chmod o-w` for the file's folder to prevent deletions.

#### Note about folder deletions

To prevent folder deletions, the folder's parent has to prevent writes (`o-w`). Alternatively, the folder can have the sticky bit (`+t`).

Comment: did it work on your system? I tried exactly the same thing but it didn't work!

Comment: Instead of using `chmod a+r,og-w` I used `chown root:root` and then `chmod 700` .I also tried `chmod 400` but nothing helped!

Comment: @Nullpointer: Found why, deletion permissions are from the file's folder (not the file). Edited answer.

Comment: Okay let me check it out!

Comment: I am still able to delete complete directory.I think Only option is to create two users!

Comment: @Nullpointer: Deletions take perms. from the parent directory.

Comment: Thanks, I checked it is working fine. Sorry for the late reply though, I was super busy with some pending chores.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but somehow

`chmod 700` doesn't stop others from deleting the directory

**1.Best option is to alias**

`rm` and `rmdir`  with

`sudo rm` and `sudo rmdir` so that every time you use `rm` ubuntu will ask for admin password.

To make this permanent add this alias entry in `~/.bash_aliases`

**2.One more option is**

Create two user accounts

one as administrator

other as general user

Don't add this general user in **sudoers** group so he won't be able to delete anything other than his home directory.

Let other use this general user and you use administrator user